# generate parent nodes from leaf nodes (child nodes array) in a hierarchical tree structure

Tags: javascript, tree

I have an array of leaf node (child nodes) and I want to find the parent nodes to them. I have a tree of approx 44000 nodes.

the leaf node array for this example is

```
const leafNodes = ["13020101",
  "13020102",
  "13020103"]
```

When I run my code I get the following node (which is working):

```
const allNodesNeededToGenerateANodeTree = [
    "13000000",
    "13020000",
    "13020100",
    "13020101",
    "13020102",
    "13020103",
]
```

I would like to know how I can make my code more efficient as now I use **multiple forEach** loops to generate

1. the segment - level 1
2. the main group - level 2
3. the group - level 3
4. commodity class - level 4 (which are the leaf nodes I send in as input)

My code:

```
Eclass.find({}, "codedName preferredName").sort({ codedName: 1 })
  .then(data => {
    // find segment nodes
    leafNodes.forEach(leafNode => {
      data.forEach(item => {
        if (item.codedName !== undefined && !nodes.includes(item.codedName) && leafNode.substring(0, 2) === item.codedName.substring(0, 2) && item.codedName.substring(2, 4) === "00") {
          nodes.push(item.codedName);
        }
      });
    });
    return data;
  })
  .then(data => {
    // find main group nodes
    leafNodes.forEach(leafNode => {
      data.forEach(item => {
        if (item.codedName !== undefined && !nodes.includes(item.codedName) && leafNode.substring(0, 4) === item.codedName.substring(0, 4) && item.codedName.substring(4, 6) === "00") {
          nodes.push(item.codedName);
        }
      });
    });
    return data;
  })
  .then(data => {
    // find group nodes
    leafNodes.forEach(leafNode => {
      data.forEach(item => {
        if (item.codedName !== undefined && !nodes.includes(item.codedName) && leafNode.substring(0, 6) === item.codedName.substring(0, 6) && item.codedName.substring(6, 8) === "00") {
          nodes.push(item.codedName);
        }
      });
    });
    // put the leaf nodes (commodity classes) into the nodes array
    const allNodesNeededToGenerateANodeTree = [...nodes, ...leafNodes].sort();
    console.log(allNodesNeededToGenerateANodeTree);
    res.status(200).json(allNodesNeededToGenerateANodeTree);
    return allNodesNeededToGenerateANodeTree;
  });
```

example "data:

```
[{
  "id": "13000000",
  "children": [{
    "id": "13010000",
    "children": [{
      "id": "13010100",
      "children": [{
        "id": "13010190",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13010190 Feasibility analysis (unspecified)"
      }],
      "name": "130101 Feasibility analysis"
    }, {
      "id": "13010200",
      "children": [{
        "id": "13010290",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13010290 Product definition (concept definition, unspecified)"
      }],
      "name": "130102 Product definition (concept definition)"
    }, {
      "id": "13010300",
      "children": [{
        "id": "13010301",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13010301 Function definition (specification total product level)"
      }, {
        "id": "13010302",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13010302 Function definition (specification system level)"
      }, {
        "id": "13010303",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13010303 Function definition (specification part level)"
      }, {
        "id": "13010390",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13010390 Function definition (unspecified)"
      }],
      "name": "130103 Function definition"
    }, {
      "id": "13010400",
      "children": [{
        "id": "13010490",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13010490 Concept interpretation (unspecified)"
      }],
      "name": "130104 Concept interpretation"
    }, {
      "id": "13010500",
      "children": [{
        "id": "13010590",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13010590 Patent and licence (concept development, unspecified)"
      }],
      "name": "130105 Patent and licence (concept development)"
    }, {
      "id": "13010600",
      "children": [{
        "id": "13010690",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13010690 Package (concept development, unspecified)"
      }],
      "name": "130106 Package (concept development)"
    }, {
      "id": "13010700",
      "children": [{
        "id": "13010790",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13010790 Judgment (concept development, unspecified)"
      }],
      "name": "130107 Judgment (concept development)"
    }, {
      "id": "13010800",
      "children": [{
        "id": "13010890",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13010890 Physics (concept development, unspecified)"
      }],
      "name": "130108 Physics (concept development)"
    }, {
      "id": "13010900",
      "children": [{
        "id": "13010990",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13010990 Product optimization (concept development, unspecified)"
      }],
      "name": "130109 Product optimization (concept development)"
    }, {
      "id": "13011000",
      "children": [{
        "id": "13011090",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13011090 Visual concept (unspecified)"
      }],
      "name": "130110 Visual concept"
    }, {
      "id": "13011100",
      "children": [{
        "id": "13011190",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13011190 Product surveying (concept development, unspecified)"
      }],
      "name": "130111 Product surveying (concept development)"
    }, {
      "id": "13019000",
      "children": [{
        "id": "13019090",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13019090 Concept development (Other, unspecified)"
      }],
      "name": "130190 Concept development (Other)"
    }],
    "name": "1301 Concept development"
  }, {
    "id": "13020000",
    "children": [{
      "id": "13020100",
      "children": [{
        "id": "13020101",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13020101 Specification performance (general product construction)"
      }, {
        "id": "13020102",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13020102 Constructional performance (general product construction)"
      }, {
        "id": "13020103",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13020103 Drawing setting-up, STRAK (general product construction)"
      }, {
        "id": "13020104",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13020104 Tolerance Testing (general product construction)"
      }, {
        "id": "13020105",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13020105 Constructional consequence analysis (general product construction)"
      }, {
        "id": "13020106",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13020106 Calculation, Simulation (general product construction)"
      }, {
        "id": "13020107",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13020107 Verification, Validation (general product construction)"
      }, {
        "id": "13020190",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13020190 General product construction (unspecified)"
      }],
      "name": "130201 General product construction"
    }, {
      "id": "13020200",
      "children": [{
        "id": "13020290",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13020290 Construction product acoustics (unspecified)"
      }],
      "name": "130202 Construction product acoustics"
    }, {
      "id": "13029000",
      "children": [{
        "id": "13029090",
        "children": [],
        "name": "13029090 Construction (development activity)"
      }],
      "name": "130290 Mechanical construction (Other)"
    }],
    "name": "1302 Mechanical construction"
  }]
}]
```

Comment: If your ids are always structured as "<segment><main group><group><class>" you can determin the parents directly from the leaf id

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik I have thought about that, but do you have an idea of how to translate that to code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will do something like this:

```
const leafNodes = ["13020101", "13020102", "13020103"];
var nodes = [];
for (const leafNode of leafNodes) {
  // Determins the parents
  //
  var segment   = leafNode.substr(0, 2).padEnd(8, '0');
  var mainGroup = leafNode.substr(0, 4).padEnd(8, '0');
  var group     = leafNode.substr(0, 6).padEnd(8, '0');

  // Add the parents in the nodes list
  //
  addNode(nodes, segment);
  addNode(nodes, mainGroup);
  addNode(nodes, group);
  addNode(nodes, leafNode);
};

nodes.sort();

console.log(nodes);
```

where the addNode function can be something like this:

```
function addNode(nodes, node) {
  // Check if the id is already present in nodes
  //
  var isAlreadyIn = nodes.indexOf(node) !== -1;

  // if not present
  //
  if (!isAlreadyIn) {
    // add the node
    //
    nodes.push(node);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are just iterating an array you should use `Array.forEach`. Using `Array.map` as you do is just creating  avoidable GC and allocation overheads. Even better in terms of performance and memory use `for (const node of leafNodes) {`